# fat model and skinny controller design confusion between the controller method and model method

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, model, controller

i'm newbie in MVC (using codeIgniter as my example) and i have read MVC fat model and skinny controller for like 3 times, what i got :

- model does the hardwork while controller calls the model and passes the data to be rendered by view

but i have one confusion , example i have an admin page that would delete product data in the db, i would have this codes (using codeIgniter):

```
public function deleteProduct($id = '')
    {
        if( is_digit($id))
        {
            $this->load->model('productModel');
            $this->productModel->deleteById($id);

            //oops product has images in another DB table and in server, so i need to delete it
            $success = $this->_deleteProductImages($id);
        }
        else
        {
            //redirect because of invalid param
        }

            //if success TRUE then load the view and display success
            //else load the view and display error
    }


protected function _deleteProductImages($productId)
{
        $this->load->model('productModel');

        //return array of images path
        $imgs = $this->productModel->getImagesPath($productId);

        // after i got the imgs data, then delete the image in DB that references to the $productId
        $this->productModel->deleteImage($productId);
        foreach($imgs as $imgPath)
        {
            if(file_exists $imgPath) unlink($imgPath);
        }
}
```

my question is :

in the concept of thin controller and fat model, should i move the method `_deleteProductImages($id)` to my productModel or should i leave it like that? if you have another better approach then please guide me here

Comment: CodeIgniter does not implement MVC. What it implements is Rails-like design, which only borrows names for things from MVC.

Comment: erm i didn't know that before(newbie here) but how about the CI's class like `CI_Controller`, and `CI_Model` don't they already state that CI uses MVC?

Comment: MVC is a design pattern. It does not matter what you call your classes. it is a bout responsibilities. The MVC pattern consists of two **layers**: mode layer an presentation layer. Presentation layer contains mostly controllers (which are responsible for altering the state of model layer and the current view instance based on user inpuy) and views (which contain all of the UI logic and juggle multiple templates). The model layer contains all of the domain business logic and rules. **Model is not a class**. Instead it contains structures that deal with application, storage and domain logic.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i searched alot about "php framework implements mvc" and i shocked that many php framework such as cakePHP(i dont mean to start a debate which framework is good or what) doesnt really implement mvc while they claim they do.. Do u have suggestion which framework that implements(for real) mvc? cause it would be a lot of effort to search and configuring it one by one

Comment: Framework it self actually cannot implement MVC. It can only provide tools, that let you use that design pattern. The two major ones which provide such tools are Zend Framework 2 and Symfony 2 (but I would recommend to avoid ZF2 for now, it has somewhat questionable code quality). Also the new Laravel has been moving toward a better towards something that lets you used MVC-inspired design pattern, but jury is still out on that one. **The bottom line** is this: you cannot learn MVC from a framework. You have to understand the pattern and then apply it to the framework that you work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a method in my model for the deletion of products. This method would do ALL of the work required to delete a product (including deleting associated DB records, files, etc).

The method would return TRUE if the operation was successful.

In the event that an associated record or file couldn't be deleted, I'd log that error in it's operation, possibly raise an error message in the UI and continue.

The method may call other methods in other models...for instance, I may have a product_attributes model that stores attributes for all products. That model might have a method: delete_by_product_id(). In that case, my product model would call product_attributes->delete_by_product_id(), which would handle the deletion of the associated records.